# Linq equivalent in lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this structure of class
Flight
..OriginDestinations
....FlightSegments

My question is prett easy, what can be equivalent in lambda expression:

```
var result1 = (
    from sf in selectedFlights
    from odo in sf.OriginDestinationOptions
    from fs in odo.FlightSegments
    select new FlightNumberAndClass {
        FlightNumber = fs.FlightNumber,
        FlightClass = fs.FlightClass
    });
```

where result1 is type of `IEnumerable<FlightNumberAndClass>`

I tried this but:

```
var result2 =
    selectedFlights.Select(
        x => x.OriginDestinationOptions.Select(
            y =>
                y.FlightSegments.Select(
                    z => new FlightNumberAndClass {
                        FlightNumber = z.FlightNumber,
                        FlightClass = z.FlightClass
                    }
                    )
            )
        );
```

it gives me result2 is type of *"something like"* `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<FlightNumberAndClass>>>`

Comment: Rather than posting the full working code i'll provide with a tip: use SelectMany instead of Select when you do a select of a collection. It will "flatten" the result.

Comment: @PeterBons Even without full working code, that's worth posting as an answer. It's entirely correct and should be more than enough to help the OP along.

Comment: @downvoter Could you enlighten me about your downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) projects each element of a sequence to an `IEnumerable<T>` and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
IEnumerable<FlightNumberAndClass> result2 = selectedFlights
    .SelectMany(sf => sf.OriginDestinationOptions
        .SelectMany(odo => odo.FlightSegments
            .Select(fs => new FlightNumberAndClass 
                {
                    FlightNumber = fs.FlightNumber,
                    FlightClass = fs.FlightClass
                }
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In situation like this you can use `SelectMany` like this example:

```
List<List<List<string>>> list1 = new List<List<List<string>>>
            {
                new List<List<string>> {
                new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e"},
                new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e"},
                new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e"}
                },
                new List<List<string>> {
                new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e"},
                new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e"},
                new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e"}
                },
                new List<List<string>> {
                new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e"},
                new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e"},
                new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e"}
                }
            };

            var result = list1.SelectMany(a => a.SelectMany(b => b.Select(c => c))).ToList();
```